# Javascript Unterminated string constant syntax

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a js file to convert a .h file to a .cs file. I go to this point and it says "gencsinc.js(26, 153) Microsoft JScript compilation error: Unterminated string constant" the line that is 26 is below.

```
fout.Write('using System;\r\n\namespace PortableDeviceConstants\r\n\{\r\n\class PortableDevicePKeys\r\n\{\r\n\static PortableDevicePKeys()\r\n\{\r\n\');
```

Comment: `n\{\r\n\'` at the end is escaping the quote. Escape the last backslash: `'n\{\r\n\\'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping last quote character:

```
...\');
```

Just remove the slash `\` to close the string.

Comment: thanks much! I do not have much js experience but you nailed it,